# using onclick from HTMLservice to run multiple tasks

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

In the following code, I wanted the button "Add Lines" to:

- run the function 'MoreRentals_fromSidebar' from code.gs in the SpreadsheetApp
- then "google.script.host.close();" to close the sidebar

When I try to stack the commands, nothing happens. If I try to invoke the submitForm function to run the two commands, nothing happens (although I thought this was working last week and has now stopped).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    function getDataFromHtml(idData) {
      if (!idData)
          idData = "mydata_htmlservice";
      var dataEncoded = document.getElementById(idData).innerHTML;
      var data = JSON.parse(atob(dataEncoded));
      return data;
    }

    function initialize() {
      var data = getDataFromHtml();
      // I would have expected to be able to accept the two parameters but whichever is coded second does not get set.
      //document.getElementById("myAgency").innerText = data.agency;
      //document.getElementById("myRow").innerText = data.row;

      // My workaround is to create the header of the sidebar to contain the agency and the line number
      var arr = data.first.split("##");
      document.getElementById('myTitle').innerText  = arr[0]+"\n@ line "+arr[1];

      //alert(arr[0]+"\n\n"+arr[1]);  // used for debugging
    }

    window.onload = initialize; //Note that there is no "()". It must be this way for this to work!
</script>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
   <script>
     function submitForm() {
       //alert('in submitForm: '+document.getElementById("RentalLinesForm");
       google.script.run.MoreRentals_fromSidebar(document.getElementById('RentalLinesForm'));
       google.script.host.close();
     }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1 id="myTitle" ></h1>
   <form id="RentalLinesForm">
     <label for="numLines">Number of lines to add</label>
     <input type="text" id="numLines" name="numLines"><br><br>
     <div>
       <label for="location">Where to place the new lines:</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="above" name="location" value="above">
       <label for="above">Above line</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="below" name="location" value="below">
       <label for="below">Below line</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="bottom" name="location" value="bottom">
       <label for="bottom">At bottom</label>
       <br><br><input type="button" value="Add Lines" onclick="google.script.run.MoreRentals_fromSidebar(document.getElementById('RentalLinesForm'));">
       <br><br><input type="button" value="DONE" onclick="google.script.host.close();">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First I wouldn't send `document.getElementById('RentalLinesForm')` in your `MoreRentals_fromSidebar()`.  Instead I would gather the values from the sidebar and if no dates, send as an array.  If dates then send as JSON.  Second the `google.script.run` is asynchronous so they don't wait for the first to finish before the second one executes.  You don't show your `MoreRentals_fromSidebar()` but if you can capture errors I'll bet there is an error from the parameter `document.getElementById('RentalLinesForm')`

Comment: Start by fixing the basic document structure of your HTML: There should not be script tags out of the html tags

Comment: This code actually works as is.  Does anyone know why I can't stack the  "google.script.host.close();" after the  "google.script.run.MoreRentals_fromSidebar(document.getElementById('RentalLinesForm'));" in the onClick or why it won't work if the onClick points at the function submitForm ?